# Proving uniform continuity

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

$f $ continuous, $f(x+1)=f(x)$ for all $x \implies f$ uniformly continuous

I remember theorem where if the domain is compact and f is continuous then f is uniformly continuous. I'm not sure what's the significance of f(x+1) = f(x), I think that this is just a constant function across the domain. I'm not sure if I understand the question or if my intuition is correct.

Comment: Is $f$ continuous?

Comment: Yes it is indeed

Comment: Note $\sin(2\pi x)$ satisfies the hypotheses.

Comment: The statement that $f(x+1) = f(x)$ for all $x$ does *not* mean the function is constant.  But it is still pretty nice.

Comment: Since $f$ is continuous on $[0,1]$ (that is a compact set), $f$ is uniformly continuous over $[0,1]$.<br> 
Since $f(x)=f(x+1)$, $f$ is uniformly continuous on $\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

$f$ is uniformly continuous at $[0,1]$.
let $\epsilon>0$ given.

$\exists \eta_1>0 \;\; \forall x,y\in [0,1]$

$|x-y|<\eta_1 \implies |f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon$.

For all $x,y \in \mathbb R$ such that

$0<y-x<\frac{1}{2}$
we have two cases

$\lfloor y \rfloor =\lfloor x \rfloor$
$\implies |(x-\lfloor x \rfloor)-(y-\lfloor y \rfloor)|=|x-y|$

OR

$\lfloor y \rfloor =\lfloor x \rfloor +1$
$\implies |(x-\lfloor x\rfloor)-(y-\lfloor y \rfloor -1|=|x-y|$.

take $ \eta=\inf(\frac{1}{2},\eta_1)$

as

$f(x-\lfloor x\rfloor)=f(x)$ and
$x-\lfloor x \rfloor \in [0,1]$

$f(y-\lfloor y \rfloor -1)=f(y)$

thus

$|x-y|<\eta \implies |f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon$.